# Need to select one image one time

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function jobTitleDetails(id, jobTitle) {
  document.getElementById("subject").value = jobTitle;
  document.getElementById('img_' + id).className += ' jobtitle';
}
```

```css
.jobtitle:active {
  border: 5px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<img class="img-thumbnail" id="img_1" src="1.png" title="Pole Erection" alt="Pole Erection" onclick="javascript:jobTitleDetails('1', 'Pole Erection');" style="height:65px; width:65px; cursor:pointer;" />
<img class="img-thumbnail" id="img_2" src="1.png" title="Stringing as per BEL" alt="Stringing as per BEL" onclick="javascript:jobTitleDetails('2', 'Stringing as per BEL');" style="height:65px; width:65px; cursor:pointer;">
```

Comment: Kindly explain bit more. It will helpful for the community to answer your queries quickly and faster

Answer (score 0):

Almost done.Remove the active in css `jobtitle` class.You could see the clicked element color and check length of the selected img using `jobtitle` class length

```js
function jobTitleDetails(id, jobTitle) {
  //document.getElementById("subject").value = jobTitle;
  document.getElementById('img_' + id).className += ' jobtitle';
  var len =  document.querySelectorAll('.jobtitle').length;
  console.log('selected img:'+len)
}
```

```css
.jobtitle {
  border: 5px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<img class="img-thumbnail" id="img_1" src="1.png" title="Pole Erection" alt="Pole Erection" onclick="javascript:jobTitleDetails('1', 'Pole Erection');" style="height:65px; width:65px; cursor:pointer;" />
<img class="img-thumbnail" id="img_2" src="1.png" title="Stringing as per BEL" alt="Stringing as per BEL" onclick="javascript:jobTitleDetails('2', 'Stringing as per BEL');" style="height:65px; width:65px; cursor:pointer;">
```

Comment: Accept as answer.its more helpful for future visitor

Answer (score 0):

You need remove :active in css and add code to remove old selected border.

```
 var images = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="img_"]');
  for(var i=0; i<images.length;i++){
   images[i].classList.remove("jobtitle");
  }
```

```js
function jobTitleDetails(id, jobTitle) {
  document.getElementById("subject").value = jobTitle;
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="img_"]');
  for(var i=0; i<images.length;i++){
   images[i].classList.remove("jobtitle");
  }
  document.getElementById('img_' + id).className += ' jobtitle';
  
}
```

```css
.jobtitle {
  border: 5px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<img class="img-thumbnail" id="img_1" src="1.png" title="Pole Erection" alt="Pole Erection" onclick="javascript:jobTitleDetails('1', 'Pole Erection');" style="height:65px; width:65px; cursor:pointer;" />
<img class="img-thumbnail" id="img_2" src="1.png" title="Stringing as per BEL" alt="Stringing as per BEL" onclick="javascript:jobTitleDetails('2', 'Stringing as per BEL');" style="height:65px; width:65px; cursor:pointer;">

<input type="text" id="subject">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see an element with the `id` "subject" in the DOM. That's where you get first error.

```
<img class="img-thumbnail" id="img_1" src="1.png" title="Pole Erection"  />
<img class="img-thumbnail" id="img_2" src="1.png" title="Stringing as per BEL" >

<div id="subject">&nbsp;</div>
```

Then, refactor your functionality, using event delegation and use some reusable helper functions(one function to check and remove a custom class, from all elements that they have the class, and one to add only once, the custom class):

```
function classname_presence (elem, cls) {
  var flag = elem.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'));
  return flag ? true : false;
}

function classname_remove (elem, cls) {
  if (classname_presence(elem, cls)) {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)');
    elem.className = elem.className.replace(reg, ' ');
    elem.className = elem.className.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
  }
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(classname_presence(e.target, 'img-thumbnail')){

    document.querySelectorAll('.img-thumbnail').forEach(function(element){
      classname_remove(element, 'jobTitle');
    });

    updateTitle.call(e.target);
  }
});


function updateTitle() {
    var title = this.getAttribute('title'),
    id = this.getAttribute('id').replace('img_', '');

  if(document.getElementById("subject")){
      document.getElementById("subject").innerText = title;
  }
  document.getElementById('img_' + id).className += ' jobTitle';
}
```

Finally, just update the CSS:

```
.img-thumbnail.jobtitle{
         border: 5px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Fiddle here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luciaannn/fm9uct4e/22/)

Comment: Forgot to mention... remove the inline "onclick" method and place it in a js file. Also, make use of the DOM attributes of the elements, so you can easily reuse the data from there(e.g. the title attribute, so you will hook the element and get the title dynamically, instead of hardcoding it on function execution)